# What alternatives do I have to a global static object constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, static, global

I have a solution that lets me easily add functionality to a microcontroller project by just (adding and) including some files. The whole initializatin of the hardware happens automagically as the header file is included. This approach is based on (the constructor of) a global static object:

*main.cpp*:

```
#include "led.h"  // <-- Led gets initialized automagically

int main ()
  {
    Led::TurnOn ();
    // ...
    Led::TurnOff ();
  }
```

*led.h*:

```
class Led
  {
  public:
    Led () noexcept;

  public:
    static void TurnOn ();
    static void TurnOff ();
  };
```

*led.cpp*:

```
/* Compiler calls constructor before first use of any method in
   this compilation unit  */
Led theLed;

Led::Led () noexcept  // <-- Shall not throw
  {
    // Initialize led
  }

void Led::TurnOn ()
  {
    // Turn led on
  }

void Led::TurnOff ()
  {
    // Turn led off
  }
```

I wonder, whether a singleton / factory method approach should be used. But they both seem to imply lazy initialization (and are therefore not deterministic at runtime) or need the programmer to explicitly call some initialization method. (I know that my example is non-deterministic as well)

So my question: "**What alternatives do I have to achieve similar behavior?**" and probably: what is the standard approach to initialize hardware in embedded projects (that need no de-initialization of any hardware)?

*edit: corrected a misleading wording*

Comment: Unrelated: Shouldn't you be calling `theLed.TurnOn()` and `theLed.TurnOff()`? What if you have more than one Led?

Comment: @immibis: the methods are static and `theLed` is not visible from main.cpp. Therefore `::`. And I would probably call the leds `PowerLed`, `ErrorLed` or anything and put them in a namespace like `Hardware::Led`. So I could turn on via `Hardware::Led::PowerLed::TurnOn ()`.

Comment: Do all these LEDs have fundamentally different logic for initialisation and usage, or is the only difference in I/O registers?

Comment: @paddy: They do have slightly different initialization. Some of it could however be generalized.

Comment: It would be `Hardware::Led::PowerLed.TurnOn()`, but I'd say the namespace is just clutter unless your program is quite big (and with many things besides LEDs).

Comment: *"happens automagically as the header file is included"*. Not in your example, the global is only in led.cpp.

Comment: BTW, Why do you want singleton(s) ?

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, you are right. The constructor is called before any other method of the compilation unit in which the object is instantiated. So it's up to the compiler on when exactly to call my initialization code. But at least it _feels_ like "including the file initializes the leds".

Comment: @Jarod42: It seems like my english lets you assume that I _wish I had_ a singleton solution. (Sorry.) What I wanted to express is that I am not sure whether this should be implemented as singleton.

Comment: So, following seems to do the job:
`int main ()
  {
    Led led;
    led.TurnOn();
    /*...*/
    led.TurnOff();
  }`

Comment: @Jarod42: What I dislike about this approach is, that if you have lots of leds to initialize (and again, leds just serve as an example), you need to clutter your `main` method with lots of initialization. Of course you can encapsulate all those initializations in a function, but that feels ugly to me. Why not let the compiler do the work for me?

Comment: I personally think global state initialization before main is sort of ugly. It can be hidden in any object file, the order is not guaranteed by the standard (most of the time in the order you passed it to the linker). Also, many tools regarding debugging/profiling/instrumentation and whatnot don't deal particularly well with code before main. This is one of those cases where I vastly prefer being explicit to relying on implicit compiler/language behavior.